# XML and making extended types

Tags: xml, validation, xsd

I want to be able to validate a field in an XML using an XSD, and one of the fields have to be of type

```
  <ABC>ABC1</ABC>
```

up to ABC999, or

```
  <ABC>none<ABC>
```

To this end I have made an XSD for validating this field as follows:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Format1">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:pattern value="ABC([0-9]{1,4})"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Format2">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
        <xs:enumeration value="none"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>

<xs:simpleType name="Allowed">
    <xs:union memberTypes="Format1 Format2"/>
</xs:simpleType>
```

And the element is as follows:

```
<xs:element name="ABC" type="Allowed"/>
```

However, my tests pass using a tag I know is faulty, for example:

```
<ABC>1</ABC>
```

Will pass the tests.

Do I need to define the simpletypes in a specific order in the XSD or am I doing something else wrong? The regex seems fine to me.

Regards

---

This gives me errors saying complexType needs a name attribute.. If i add a name attribute, the tests pass, even though they shouldn't

---

validate.py:

```
def test_schema_structure(self):
    f = open('docvalidator.xsd')
    doc = ET.parse(f)
    xml_schema = ET.XMLSchema(doc)

    featuresubset = ET.parse('featuresubset.xsd')
    xml_schema.validate(featuresubset)
```

xml to validate:

```
 <!-- other elements --->
   <xs:documentation>
    <Countries>
      <Country type="EU">Spain</Group>
      <Country type="EU">Greece</Group>
      <country type="EU">Germany</Group>
    </Countries>
    <ABC>asdasd</ABC>
    <Description>Some text</Description>
    <Consumers/>
  </xs:documentation>
```

Comment: Can you post minimal but complete samples of schema and instance document that allow us to reproduce the problem? Which parser or tool do you use to validate the XML?

Comment: I tried to reproduce the problem with Visual Studio, using your types and the additional declaration  ` <xs:element name="Root">
    <xs:complexType>
      <xs:sequence maxOccurs="unbounded">
        <xs:element name="ABC" type="Allowed"/>
      </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>` to allow me to construct a sample, then I used the sample  `<Root>
  <ABC>ABC1</ABC>
  <ABC>ABC9999</ABC>
  <ABC>none</ABC>
  <ABC>foo</ABC>
  <ABC>1</ABC>
  
</Root>` and the last two `ABC` elements are marked correctly as invalid.

Comment: @MartinHonnen Im using python and lxml / XMLSchema to validate.

I will post better example, but your code seems to be helping.

Comment: nevermind, it didn't work. My ABC tag is a child  of another tag, does that matter? I only want to be able to use `<xs:element name = "ABC" type="Allowed"/>` and then have that use the other simpleTypes i defined.

Comment: Sorry, but that is not a complete and minimal sample, a `complexType` as a top level element needs to have a `name` attribute. And I don't think we need all the other elements to identify the problem.  As for `<xs:element name = "ABC" type="Allowed"/>`, that is fine to use the declared type. But to tell whether your schema should work or whether there is a problem with your validation tool, we need to see minimal but complete samples of schema and instance document allowing us to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Tried adding more information.. Had to rename some stuff first

Answer (score 1):

I think that a facet combining the ABC.* and none would simplify matters:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Allowed">
  <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
      <xs:pattern value="ABC([0-9]{1,4})|none"/>
  </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

Using two different types with the same element name in the same position is bound to create problems - not sure how that union can be handled by some parsers.

Comment: Using `<xs:element name="ABC" type="Allowed"/>   '\n'  <your code>` will make the tests pass even if i have a tag thats `<ABC>foo</ABC>`

Other than that, thanks, that seems like a much better option for making the code more readable and light!

Comment: Maybe you aren't using the right validator? `javax.xml.bind.UnmarshalException
 - with linked exception:
[org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 4; columnNumber: 17; cvc-pattern-valid: Value 'foo' is not facet-valid with respect to pattern 'ABC([0-9]{1,4})|none' for type 'Allowed'.]`

Comment: I think I broke it because now it says `No matching global declaration for the validationroot`.

Will investigate a bit further